# Javascript - Can't push to inner object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, electron

I have an object like so:

```
var chosen=[{nrChart:1, chosenGraphics:[]}];
```

with which I use [electron-window-manager](https://github.com/TamkeenLMS/electron-window-manager#class-windowmanagershareddata) to create a sharedData like so:

```
windowManager.sharedData.set("chosen",chosen);
```

After that I fetch that sharedData in another js file like so:

```
that.exp = windowManager.sharedData.fetch("chosen");
```

So far, so good. The problem now is that I can do `that.exp.push(1)` but not `that.exp[0].chosenGraphics.push(1)`, which returns the new length but the array stays the same.

What's happening?

**Structure of the object that.exp for clarification:**

[image: Structure of the object that.exp for clarification]

**Edit: chosenGraphics: Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Guzj.jpg) expanded **
[image]

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: Have you tried setting the shared data again after the push? It's possible that it won't update automatically.

Comment: expand "chosenGraphics: Array[1]" node

Comment: Added new photo @Igor

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out why I couldn't push to chosenGraphics but I found out a solution which was to make a clone of the object with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(windowManager.sharedData.fetch("chosen")));`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `chosenGraphics` defined multiple times in your object `that.exp[0]`. There is an array called `chosenGraphics`, and there are two functions called `chosenGraphics`. When you call `that.exp[0].chosenGraphics.push(1)`, it is probably trying to execute `push` on one of the functions, which don't have a `push` property or method.

Comment: Ty for the answer. Those functions set and get are not done by me but automatically when I do `windowManager.sharedData.set("chosen",chosen);`. With that said, how can I solve this?

Comment: Also, if the functions don't have a `push` method I would get an error. Instead I get an integer said the new length of `chosenGraphics`.

Comment: What does your raw json look like coming back from `windowManager.sharedData.fetch`?

Comment: `"[{"nrChart":1,"chosenGraphics":[{"name":"subj_1_MSV_LWRA","id":2,"color":"asd"}],"$$hashKey":"object:2"}]"`